# Recursive dictionary walking in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, python-2.x

I am new to python and trying to create a recursive dictionary walker that outputs a path to each item in the dictionary.

Below is my code including some sample data.  The goal is to import weather data from weather underground and publish into mqtt topics on a raspberry pi.  (The mqtt code all runs fine and is independent of this, for this I just need to generate the paths)

The issue that I am having is that when I reach the 'forecastday' element of the dict, my function is returning what looks like json data instead of recursing further into the path.

I have tried a few methods of walking the dict, but when the examples started getting into 'generators' etc, things were starting to get above my head a little.

(The test data does not contain any private information, it is the general weather report for my nearest town)

Thanks

```
import json

def print_path(root, data, path):

    for element in data.keys():
        if not isinstance(data[element], dict):
            print root + path + element, data[element]
        else:
            print_path(root, data[element], element+"/")

json_string = u'{"response":{"version":"0.1","termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html","features":{"almanac":1,"astronomy":1,"conditions":1,"forecast":1}},"current_observation":{"image":{"url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png","title":"Weather Underground","link":"http://www.wunderground.com"},"display_location":{"full":"Llanelli, United Kingdom","city":"Llanelli","state":"","state_name":"United Kingdom","country":"UK","country_iso3166":"GB","zip":"00000","magic":"11","wmo":"03605","latitude":"51.67610931","longitude":"-4.15666723","elevation":"17.00000000"},"observation_location":{"full":"Llanelli, CARMARTHENSHIRE","city":"Llanelli","state":"CARMARTHENSHIRE","country":"GB","country_iso3166":"GB","latitude":"51.679951","longitude":"-4.140789","elevation":"40 ft"},"estimated":{},"station_id":"ICARMART4","observation_time":"Last Updated on October 18, 8:07 AM BST","observation_time_rfc822":"Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:07:38 +0100","observation_epoch":"1476774458","local_time_rfc822":"Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:07:44 +0100","local_epoch":"1476774464","local_tz_short":"BST","local_tz_long":"Europe/London","local_tz_offset":"+0100","weather":"Mostly Cloudy","temperature_string":"49.0 F (9.4 C)","temp_f":49.0,"temp_c":9.4,"relative_humidity":"90%","wind_string":"From the West at 4.5 MPH Gusting to 6.9 MPH","wind_dir":"West","wind_degrees":272,"wind_mph":4.5,"wind_gust_mph":"6.9","wind_kph":7.2,"wind_gust_kph":"11.1","pressure_mb":"1019","pressure_in":"30.09","pressure_trend":"0","dewpoint_string":"46 F (8 C)","dewpoint_f":46,"dewpoint_c":8,"heat_index_string":"NA","heat_index_f":"NA","heat_index_c":"NA","windchill_string":"47 F (9 C)","windchill_f":"47","windchill_c":"9","feelslike_string":"47 F (9 C)","feelslike_f":"47","feelslike_c":"9","visibility_mi":"6.2","visibility_km":"10.0","solarradiation":"--","UV":"0","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)","precip_1hr_in":"0.00","precip_1hr_metric":" 0","precip_today_string":"0.07 in (2 mm)","precip_today_in":"0.07","precip_today_metric":"2","soil_moisture":"255.0","icon":"mostlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif","forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/03605.html","history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=ICARMART4","ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=51.679951,-4.140789","nowcast":""},"forecast":{"txt_forecast":{"date":"7:03 AM BST","forecastday":[{"period":0,"icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","title":"Tuesday","fcttext":"Sun and clouds mixed. High around 55F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Sun and clouds mixed. High 12C. Winds WNW at 15 to 30 km/h.","pop":"0"},{"period":1,"icon":"nt_partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif","title":"Tuesday Night","fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 43F. Winds WNW at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low 6C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":2,"icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","title":"Wednesday","fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies in the morning will give way to cloudy skies during the afternoon. High 56F. Winds NW at 10 to 15 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly to mostly cloudy. High 13C. Winds NW at 15 to 25 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":3,"icon":"nt_partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif","title":"Wednesday Night","fcttext":"A few clouds. Low 41F. Winds N at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low around 5C. Winds N at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":4,"icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","title":"Thursday","fcttext":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High 59F. Winds N at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies. High around 15C. Winds N at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":5,"icon":"nt_partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif","title":"Thursday Night","fcttext":"Partly cloudy. Low 41F. Winds NE at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low near 5C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":6,"icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","title":"Friday","fcttext":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High 58F. Winds E at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Sunshine and clouds mixed. High 14C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"},{"period":7,"icon":"nt_partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif","title":"Friday Night","fcttext":"Partly cloudy. Low 44F. Winds E at 5 to 10 mph.","fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low 6C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.","pop":"10"}]},"simpleforecast":{"forecastday":[{"date":{"epoch":"1476813600","pretty":"7:00 PM BST on October 18, 2016","day":18,"month":10,"year":2016,"yday":291,"hour":19,"min":"00","sec":0,"isdst":"1","monthname":"October","monthname_short":"Oct","weekday_short":"Tue","weekday":"Tuesday","ampm":"PM","tz_short":"BST","tz_long":"Europe/London"},"period":1,"high":{"fahrenheit":"55","celsius":"13"},"low":{"fahrenheit":"43","celsius":"6"},"conditions":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","skyicon":"","pop":0,"qpf_allday":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_day":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_night":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"snow_allday":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_day":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_night":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"maxwind":{"mph":20,"kph":32,"dir":"WNW","degrees":293},"avewind":{"mph":16,"kph":26,"dir":"WNW","degrees":293},"avehumidity":71,"maxhumidity":0,"minhumidity":0},{"date":{"epoch":"1476900000","pretty":"7:00 PM BST on October 19, 2016","day":19,"month":10,"year":2016,"yday":292,"hour":19,"min":"00","sec":0,"isdst":"1","monthname":"October","monthname_short":"Oct","weekday_short":"Wed","weekday":"Wednesday","ampm":"PM","tz_short":"BST","tz_long":"Europe/London"},"period":2,"high":{"fahrenheit":"56","celsius":"13"},"low":{"fahrenheit":"41","celsius":"5"},"conditions":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","skyicon":"","pop":10,"qpf_allday":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_day":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_night":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"snow_allday":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_day":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_night":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"maxwind":{"mph":15,"kph":24,"dir":"NW","degrees":318},"avewind":{"mph":12,"kph":19,"dir":"NW","degrees":318},"avehumidity":79,"maxhumidity":0,"minhumidity":0},{"date":{"epoch":"1476986400","pretty":"7:00 PM BST on October 20, 2016","day":20,"month":10,"year":2016,"yday":293,"hour":19,"min":"00","sec":0,"isdst":"1","monthname":"October","monthname_short":"Oct","weekday_short":"Thu","weekday":"Thursday","ampm":"PM","tz_short":"BST","tz_long":"Europe/London"},"period":3,"high":{"fahrenheit":"59","celsius":"15"},"low":{"fahrenheit":"41","celsius":"5"},"conditions":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","skyicon":"","pop":10,"qpf_allday":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_day":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_night":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"snow_allday":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_day":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_night":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"maxwind":{"mph":10,"kph":16,"dir":"N","degrees":2},"avewind":{"mph":7,"kph":11,"dir":"N","degrees":2},"avehumidity":78,"maxhumidity":0,"minhumidity":0},{"date":{"epoch":"1477072800","pretty":"7:00 PM BST on October 21, 2016","day":21,"month":10,"year":2016,"yday":294,"hour":19,"min":"00","sec":0,"isdst":"1","monthname":"October","monthname_short":"Oct","weekday_short":"Fri","weekday":"Friday","ampm":"PM","tz_short":"BST","tz_long":"Europe/London"},"period":4,"high":{"fahrenheit":"58","celsius":"14"},"low":{"fahrenheit":"44","celsius":"7"},"conditions":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partlycloudy","icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif","skyicon":"","pop":10,"qpf_allday":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_day":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"qpf_night":{"in":0.00,"mm":0},"snow_allday":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_day":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"snow_night":{"in":0.0,"cm":0.0},"maxwind":{"mph":10,"kph":16,"dir":"E","degrees":91},"avewind":{"mph":7,"kph":11,"dir":"E","degrees":91},"avehumidity":79,"maxhumidity":0,"minhumidity":0}]}},"moon_phase":{"percentIlluminated":"93","ageOfMoon":"17","phaseofMoon":"Waning Gibbous","hemisphere":"North","current_time":{"hour":"8","minute":"07"},"sunrise":{"hour":"7","minute":"46"},"sunset":{"hour":"18","minute":"15"},"moonrise":{"hour":"20","minute":"10"},"moonset":{"hour":"10","minute":"24"}},"sun_phase":{"sunrise":{"hour":"7","minute":"46"},"sunset":{"hour":"18","minute":"15"}},"almanac":{"airport_code":"EGFF","temp_high":{"normal":{"F":"55","C":"12"},"record":{"F":"66","C":"18"},"recordyear":"1997"},"temp_low":{"normal":{"F":"46","C":"7"},"record":{"F":"33","C":"0"},"recordyear":"1998"}}}'

weather_report = json.loads(json_string)

print_path("dev/blah/weather/", weather_report, "")
```

EDIT>>

This is some of the output that I get from the script

```
...
dev/blah/weather/sunrise/minute 46
dev/blah/weather/sunrise/hour 7
dev/blah/weather/sunset/minute 15
dev/blah/weather/sunset/hour 18
dev/blah/weather/sunrise/minute 46
dev/blah/weather/sunrise/hour 7
dev/blah/weather/txt_forecast/date 7:03 AM BST
dev/blah/weather/txt_forecast/forecastday [{u'title': u'Tuesday', u'icon_url': u'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif', u'fcttext_metric': u'Sun and clouds mixed. High 12C. Winds WNW at 15 to 30 km/h.', u'period': 0, u'pop': u'0', u'fcttext': u'Sun and clouds mixed. High around 55F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.', u'icon': u'partlycloudy'}, {u'title': u'Tuesday Night', u'icon_url': u'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif', u'fcttext_metric': u'Partly cloudy. Low 6C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', u'period': 1, u'pop': u'10', u'fcttext': u'Partly cloudy skies. Low 43F. Winds WNW at 5 to 10 mph.', u'icon': u'nt_partlycloudy'}, {u'title': u'Wednesday', u'icon_url': u'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif', u'fcttext_metric': u'Partly to mostly cloudy. High 13C. Winds NW at 15 to 25 km/h.', u'period': 2, u'pop': u'10', u'fcttext': u'Partly cloudy skies in the morning will give way to cloudy skies during the afternoon.
```

For the last entry here it should say

```
dev/blah/weather/txt_forecast/forecastday/0/title Tuesday
dev/blah/weather/txt_forecast/forecastday/0/icon partlycloudy
```

but instead it shows

```
[{u'title': u'Tuesday', u'icon_url': u'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif', u'fcttext_metric': u'Sun and clouds mixed. High 12C. Winds WNW at 15 to 30 km/h.', u'perio...
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Maybe you meant to additionally check for `isinstance(data[element], list)`?

Comment: Hi crickry_007, do you mean that inside the dictionary the forecastday data is stored as a list and I need to iterate that too?  I am looking to get something like /dev/blah/weather/forecast/forecastday/0/title Tuesday.

Comment: actually data.keys() will give as a list, `>>> type(_dict.keys())
<type 'list'>` however i got your intention, you are checking if the value corresponds to the key is a dictionary.

Comment: can you put some more effort in re-framing the question, i didn't get your problem exactly....

Comment: no problems. i can sort that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mix-in a regular for-loop into that recursion to iterate over the lists.

```
def print_path(root, data, path):

    for element, val in data.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            print_path(root, val, element+"/")
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            list_path = path+element+"/"
            for i, item in enumerate(val):
                print_path(root, item, list_path+str(i)+"/")
        else:
            print root + path + element, val
```

Should see `dev/blah/weather/txt_forecast/forecastday/0/title Tuesday` in the output

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as great.  Python... so much more to learn :)

Comment: Welcome. And I solved that `txt_forecast` problem already. Was simpler than I thought